# Possible to use string to refer to object property?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary, properties

I couldn't find a related question in StackOverflow, so...

I have a dictionary filled with data on planets and stars in the form of:

```
dict = {'name': value, 'mass' : value, 'radius': value, etc..}
```

the keys of this dictionary have the same name of the properties of the Planet and Star class that I am assigning their value to.

What I would like to do is to count the amount of missing information for all of the populated Star and Planet objects after I calculate certain missing fields of data based on other populated fields...

Is there any way to step through the keys of this dictionary and reference the property of Star/ Planet objects with the string that the key holds?

So something like:

```
for planetObjs in planets:
    for key in dict.iterkeys():
        if planetObj.key == None:
            countMissingDict[key] += 1
```

How would I refer to the string that key holds which is the same string used as the attribute within a Planet object? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

> `getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value`
>
> Get a named attribute from an object; `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to
>   `x.y`. When a default argument is given, it is returned when the
>   attribute doesn't exist; without it, an exception is raised in that
>   case

You can shorten your code to:

```
from collections import Counter
countMissingDict = Counter(key for planetObjs in planets for key in dic
                                         if getattr(planetObjs, key) is None)
```

<sub>**Note:** Don't use `dict` as a variable name.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `getattr`.

```
for planetObj in planets:
    for key in dict.iterkeys():
        if getattr(planetObj, key) == None:
            countMissingDict[key] += 1
```